# How do Starfleet personnel get credits or Latinum?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, money, economics

Quark's bar takes payment in Latinum; and perhaps, as discussed in [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20743/a-starfleet-officer-walks-into-quarks) - in Federation "credits" (backed by something - not clear what). Now, in another discussion e.g. in [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6931/16835), the mechanism of distributing Latinum or credit is supposedly not interesting.

Except - it's very interesting. Let's By what mechanism does a Federation subject, or military personnel ("Starfleet"), get either credits or Latinum? Is there a wage? An allowance? Savings?

Or - maybe they don't get them at all? i.e. maybe Quark logs orders then bills the Starfleet directly? I don't remember DS9 scenes with Starfleet personnel paying or settling their tab.

Comment: Come to Quark's, Quark's is fun! Come to Quark's, Don't walk, Run!

Comment: Money doesn't exist in that time (mentioned in FC when Picard was telling Lilly about what life is like in the 24th century)

Comment: @SpacePhoenix: Tell that to Quark when he asks for your payment.

Comment: @einpoklum Ireckon that Odo has plenty of stuff that he's holding over Quark