# If I want to replicate say three apples in a replicator, will they be exactly the same to the molecule or there would be slight variance?

Tags: star-trek, replicator

As far as I know, the replicator reads files from the computer library and based on that pattern it creates the object or food. If it is just materializing objects to the molecule based on that pattern, am I correct in my assumption that if want to replicate say three apples, they would be absolutely identical. Or does the device add some variance? Or are there any limitations which would not make everything identical? And yet, if it introduces some variance, how trustworthy will it be when creating more sensitive items?

Comment: Related: [This answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/28970/4383) relates the idea that replicators work on a molecular level, whereas transporters work on a quantum level. This allows for imperfections in replicated materials.

Comment: If an answer to this was desired, 'replicator' in the search-field would have immediately produced NominSim's reference. While a question framed more generally would be a nice way to get this answer, 'apples' vs 'latinum' isn't it.

Comment: @Solemnity This question isn't an exact duplicate by any means

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The files from the library may contain either a copy of an apple, copies of multiple apples, or instructions on how to generate random apples. So it's readily possible that replicators could produce random apples.

After all, if you were designing a replicator which makes food for people, you wouldn't want to produce the exact same meal every time as most people would get bored. Built in variety would be a useful feature.

It's probably possible to ask the replicator to produce identical items but it's most likely that the default setting would be to randomise.

Comment: The general dissatisfaction with replicated food might be due to just that: every instance of a meal tastes the same.  Hence we see characters preparing meals by hand from replicated (and sometime fresh) ingredients to introduce some variability in taste.

Comment: Good point but it seems that any designer with an ounce of sense would foresee that problem and build in automated variety. Maybe it's that script writers <> designers.

Comment: I don't think most people would care if the food tasted exactly the same each time. Too much/little salt, over/undercooked, etc. isn't the type of variety most people seek. I would rather every plate of spaghetti I eat be seasoned to perfection and just not eat it everyday than to have a computer that tries to create "imperfect" meals for me. Just program the replicator with 500 different spaghetti recipes and replicate them exactly the way I like each one. My tastebuds won't notice that each serving has the exact same amount of starch, maillard molecules, calories, etc. as last time.

Answer (score 0):

When Will Ryker was at Far Point Station, the being that was being held captive did, upon Ryker's request, produce a whole bowl of apples (through it's own style of replication).  I remember them all being the same species of apple but it wasn't mentioned whether they were identical or not.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the food the crew members ask the replicator is their own version of the dish. They program a version of it they way they like it, changing taste, adding spices and everything at their own taste and then they set it as their defult preferred option.

So that is also why there is an attendant at the ship bar, her/his role is to serve the crew but also to create a particular version of the drinks and foods and add some variety.

Foor example, Picard's tea.

The Earl Grey he uses his his own recipe of it. And the definition of hot is his own definition of hot.
He may have guest and they may want it warm, so he could just keep his own recipy of Earl Grey but have it warm instead... and so on...

Comment: Can you site where this information comes from, other than speculation?

Comment: Then why the heck hasn't Picard setup a 'tea, Earl Grey, hot' preference?

Comment: the Earl Grey he uses his his own recipe of it. and the definition of hot is his own definition of hot. He may have guest and they may want it warm, so he could just keep his own recipy of Earl Grey but have it warm instead... and so on...

Comment: @Monty129 The accepted answer does not report any refence to where the data come from. I can't find the exact scripts but I can remember many times when the crew played with the replicators to slightly change the result of what they were getting.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on where and who was replicated it. On a ship, They would keep only one pattern as disk space would be a valuable resource (They are ships of exploration and science, no?). The counter point to this is that replicators don't replicated exact copies of anything. Like making a copy of anything, there is some data lost or change in the reproduction of the stored item. Also, Federation replicators transpose things into the foodstuffs that come out of them, like [nutrients](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Replicator). One could theorize that the nutrients could change based on the recipient's needs, making them different. What it would all come down to is if this affects the actual taste of said foodstuffs, which the lore points to [both directions](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Replicator). It would also make scense for planet side bases and more civilen locations to have a wider variety of an object, as space isn't as much an issue.