# Where do replicator patterns come from?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, technology, replicator

We take for granted you can get almost anything you want.

But, **Where do replicator patterns come from?**

I don't recall any discussion of this.    (Possibly the only evidence I can recall is that Data orders Feline Supplement #N.)

For example:
Are they created by Starfleet Foodservices?   Are there chefs who specialize in creating replicator patterns?
Can you readily scan an object to create a replicator program?  If you request the same item multiple times, how similar are they?

---

Related, but old; different scope; and has no well-sourced answer:
[If I want to replicate say three apples in a replicator, will they be exactly the same to the molecule or there would be slight variance?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29205/if-i-want-to-replicate-say-three-apples-in-a-replicator-will-they-be-exactly-th)

Comment: When a mummy replicator pattern and a daddy replicator pattern love each other very much...