# What is latinum and where does it occur?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

We're first introduced to latinum by the Ferengi in DS9.

Latinum is now considered the go-to currency in the Star Trek universe because it's so rare and can't be replicated. Gold (Au) and diamonds (a gem made of carbon atoms linked together in a lattice structure) on the other hand can be dug up by scratching around in the dirt on earth and other planets and can also apparently be replicated.

Beyond their intrinsic 'beauty', both gold and diamonds have industrial uses including refraction of light and conduction of electricity. This begs the question, where does latinum actually come from and what is it? Is it a naturally occurring element with only a certain number of locations where it occurs? Does it have any other value beyond it's rarity and inability to be replicated?

Comment: you're looking for more information that what is here I presume? https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum , https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum

Comment: @NKCampbell Yes I read that before asking the question. Good info but it doesn't say where latinum actually comes from or what it is.

Comment: “This begs the question” — only in your [sloppy modern vernacular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question)!

Comment: Also wouldn't it be cool if Vernacular was the star system with the Federation's main latinum mining facility.

Comment: The Star Trek universe posits a large number of materials based on elements we can only presume to exist beyond the end of the known periodic table, most probably in the [Island of Stability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability).  Names for such elements on screen are often based on existing element names (dicobalt, tritanium, duranium, trilithium, etc).  It's reasonable to think that latinum, also, is another such superheavy element.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - you are confusing the phrase "beg the question" with similarly named logical fallacy. They are not the same thing.

Comment: @Davor: did they emerge separately then? Or was the former born from people misunderstanding the latter?

Comment: I just spent the whole day scratching around in my garden. **Are you sure?**

Comment: Interesting. One answer indicates that latinum is a solid and another states that it's actually a liquid.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica reasonably sure, just keep at it.

Comment: @J... Are dilithium / trilithium / dicobalt actually ever described as elements, or are they possibly chemical compounds being referred to in short form?  (e.g. a solution of titanium dioxide is "titanic acid", and dihydromorphinone is commonly just referred to as "hydromorphinone" or "Dilaudid")

Comment: @Chronocidal I vaguely recall references to that effect... not sure where.  Actually, [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Duranium#Background_information) is probably better than Memory Mine.   For duranium, at least : `This is further supported by the use of the term "duranium-235," which implies that duranium is in fact an element, one that has an isotope with an atomic weight of 235.`

Comment: @PaulD.Waite: “your sloppy modern vernacular” — ah, you mean early 21st-century English?

Comment: @PLL: I do! Ugh!

Comment: @Chronocidal Di-/Trilithium certainly sounds like a lithium variant, so that would make sense.

Comment: Is latinum really such a mystery that even knowledgeable ST people can't agree what it is?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/why-can-latinum-not-be-replicated?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 14):

It's mined and refined on-site on various moons and planets, then sent to Ferenginar (or wherever) to be minted into currency

> Huge robot-driven bulldozers shoveled the gravel onto a conveyor belt,
> which carried it into an immense box that radiated heat in
> waves--probably a smelting furnace, Ttan thought. She'd never seen one
> quite like this before, but she knew the general principle. Inside,
> the gravel was reduced to its composite minerals, then put back
> together into ingots of pure latinurn or rhodinium or carbonire or
> whatever else it had been programmed for. She couldn't see where the
> ingots came out of this one, though.
>
> "As you may have already guessed," Gul Mavek said, "Davonia is a
> working moon. We have found traces of latinum on this level. I want
> you to find the main deposit for us." Moon? Ttan wondered. Where in
> the Great Plan had they brought her?
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Devil in the Sky](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_in_the_Sky)</sup></sub>

Apparently there are deposits on Ferenginar itself.

> GOUGE-MINING MAGNATE ESCAPES DEATH
> WIFE CHARGED IN MURDER ATTEMPT
>
> In the early morning hours, latinum mining king Squeeb, son of Been, was hauled from the flaming wreckage of his skimmer by two members of his private medical staff.Though suffering from various injuries, Squeeb is expected to make a full recovery.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Trek: Legends of the Ferengi](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Legends_of_the_Ferengi)</sup></sub>

Raw latinum metal is apparently solid, not liquid. It needs to be smelted *and processed* to remove the impurities and turn it into its pure liquid form.

> Peeking around the side of the vat, Jake looked to where his friend
> pointed. A gigantic gray box stood in the middle of the cargo bay. A
> worker using an antigrav lift stood beside it, cranking the box’s top
> back to reveal a load of raw, unprocessed latinum.
>
> <sub><sup>[DS9: Highest Score](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Highest_Score)</sup></sub>

Comment: Just one disagreement with this otherwise excellent (as always) answer - your last quotation only states that Squeeb was on Ferenginar not that he did any mining there so it doesn't even imply the presence of natural Latinum on the planet. I work in the City of London where a large number of mining companies are based and many metals magnates (pun intended) live, work and travel but we don't do much mining in the square mile!

Comment: @MD-Tech - there are later mentions of large amounts of latinum on Ferenginar. I think it's reasonable to assume he made his money at home. Either way it's mined by the Ferengi

Comment: I was nitpicking I know!

Comment: They can't make ingots of pure latinum; _Who Mourns for Morn?_ makes it very clear that latinum is a liquid. And that enough latinum to make an "ingot" would represent a huge fortune; a hundred bars' worth looks like it would fit into a shot glass. [It's the silver liquid here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X171z.png).

Comment: @RossThompson - In its processed form, sure. But who knows what it looks like in its raw form?

Comment: @Valorum Sure, maybe they can make ingots of latinum ore, but that's not what the quote says. It says "pure latinum".

Comment: @RossThompson - Maybe it's solid below room temperature

Comment: @Valorum I suppose that's possible, but I boggle at the idea of someone making ingots of mercury...

Answer (score 13):

Actually, the [Memory Alpha entry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum) (already suggested in the comments) does say what it is, although only at a very superficial level:

> Latinum was a rare silver-colored liquid metal

AFAIK, neither its exact nature (and [why it cannot be replicated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5337/why-can-latinum-not-be-replicated)) nor its sources are mentioned in the canon works (this seems to be the consensus of a relevant [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskScienceFiction/comments/6a4yr4/star_trek_what_exactly_is_latinum_and_why_does_it/), too), and arguably this is the reason why such info is not included in Memory Alpha.

Regarding its sources, some info comes from licensed but non-canon works, summarized in the relevant [Memory Beta entry](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum):

> Latinum was found naturally in the form of crystals which can be
>   mined. Such crystals typically formed near pockets of nickel, iron,
>   pergium, or cobalt. (*DS9* novel: [*Devil in the Sky*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_in_the_Sky))
>
> A Federation survey of the Davon system sometime before 2348 found
>   traces of latinum on the moon Davonia. In 2355, the planets and moons
>   of the Maxia Zeta star system were discovered to be richly endowed
>   with many minerals and materials, including latinum. And in 2370 a
>   group of Horta discovered deposits of latinum on Baraddo, Bajor's
>   outermost moon. (*DS9* novel: [*Devil in the Sky*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Devil_in_the_Sky); *TNG* - [*The Lost Era*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Lost_Era)
>   novel: [*The Buried Age*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/The_Buried_Age))
>
> A large amount of latinum supposedly exists underground on
>   Ferenginar.(*DS9* reference: [*Legends of the Ferengi*](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Legends_of_the_Ferengi))

There is also a mention in the [Apocrypha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Latinum#Apocrypha) appendix of the Memory Alpha entry:

> [*Star Trek: Armada II*](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Armada_II) depicts the natural form of latinum occurring in sparse nebulae in a form that can be harvested.

In short, however mundane this may sound, it would seem to come from mining.

Comment: “What is it?” “... ... It is silver.”

Comment: So maybe it's being used to replace mercury in some applications, assuming REACH/ROHS is still in effect and latinum isn't even more poisonous...

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis it's what finally did in fluorscent lights, when an RoHS fluorescent tube cost 12,000 units...

Comment: It might be worth referencing that latinum is seen on-screen in the DS9 episode [Who Mourns for Morn?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Morn%3F) (S06E12) - and is a silver-coloured liquid at approximately room temperature

Comment: This doesn't explain what Latinum is, in a deeper sense. So what if it's a sliver-colored liquid metal? What about it makes it so valuable and used as the commodity mediating exchanges?

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica: Presumably the inability to replicate it. Until 200 years ago, gold had no real intrinsic value (it's a pretty metal, but lots of metals are pretty), but we used it as a basis for value because it was an intrinsically highly limited resource, that didn't spoil, and was easily subdividable. When replicators can make gold, it's useless as a value store, so you need to come up with some other medium for trade when two civilizations don't accept each other's fiat currencies.

Comment: @einpoklum-reinstateMonica Arguably, we cannot extract information that is not there; if *silver-colored liquid metal* is all we have, we note that down and we move on. Edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @ShadowRanger- what are you talking about? Gold has been valuable and sought after since ancient times

Comment: @NKCampbell: It has no *intrinsic* value. That is, it's no good for eating, building anything that keeps you alive, keeps you warm, defends you against attack, or serves any productive use aside from "look pretty, rare, easy to break apart and put back together". It's valuable because we agreed it's valuable, that's all (the modern intrinsic value is in electronics), and we agreed it's valuable because it has all the attributes that make it useful as a currency; you can't make more of it easily, it doesn't go bad, and you can break it up for smaller transactions.

Comment: Point is, it had value, but not *intrinsic* value; in a hunter-gatherer society, it's far less valuable than all the things that actually help you survive, or do literally anything useful. More advanced civilizations need a medium of exchange (barter can't work at large scale), and gold has desirable characteristics for a store of value, that's all. Similarly, once gold is easily available, it becomes worthless as currency, so something that *can't* be replicated must replace it for scenarios where fiat currency isn't trusted (Ferengi don't trust anyone not to debase their own currency).